# How to find out if TextView text content has been cut off

Tags: android

I can set max line in my TextView in layout xml file.
In my code, after I call setText() to the TextView, how can I find out if the text content has been cut off (i.e. the text is longer than the max line)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

So while I haven't tested this yet (sorry no sdk setup in front of me)

Your TextView should have a Paint object created for it. Now I would assume that TextPaint has been constructed with the correct padding and offset for the background image of the text view. So you should be able to do something like

```
TextView a = getViewById(R.id.textview);
TextPaint paint = a.getPaint();
Rect rect = new Rect();
String text = String.valueOf(a.getText());
paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), rect);
if(rect.height() > a.getHeight() || rect.width() > a.getWidth()) {
Log.i("TEST", "Your text is too large");
}
```

Comment: Just change `rect.getWidth()` to `rect.width()`.

Comment: If anyone trying to just avoid text cut-offs in `TextView`, please see [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it in my search for a similar answer and wanted to offer the solution that I found, in case anyone else is wondering.

This worked for me:

```
TextView myTextView = rootView.getViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
if (myTextView.getLineCount() > myTextView.getMaxLines()) {
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `==` instead of `>`. When I tested this, my cut off text was returning only the number of lines shown when calling `getLineCount` rather than the total number of lines represented by the string.

Comment: Line count and maxlines can be same and char like 'g' can still be clipped

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
mTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        ViewTreeObserver obs = mTextView.getViewTreeObserver();
        obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        int height = mTextView.getHeight();
        int scrollY = mTextView.getScrollY();
        Layout layout = mTextView.getLayout();
        int firstVisibleLineNumber = layout.getLineForVertical(scrollY);
        int lastVisibleLineNumber = layout.getLineForVertical(height + scrollY);

        //check is latest line fully visible
        if (mTextView.getHeight() < layout.getLineBottom(lastVisibleLineNumber)) {
            // TODO you text is cut
        }
    }
});
```